# How do I delete landscape specific xml layout file?

Tags: android, xml

Accidentally created a *.xml(land) file and I want to delete it. I tried going into the project view and deleting it from the 'layount_land', but when I do that not only is the land-xml deleted, the normal xml-file that I wish to keep get deleted as well?

I saw that if you have Windows Operating System this file could be deleted from Windows Explorer(?) but since Im on a MacBook that won't be possible.

What should I do?

Comment: It's functionality of SafeDelete with android studio.
To disable this functionality follow with below details.
When you will click delete option then uncheck "Safe Delete" option from Delete dialog so it'll not delete other related files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I saw that if you have Windows Operating System this file could be deleted from Windows Explorer(?) but since Im on a MacBook that won't be possible.

You can delete the file from **finder** on a MacBook. There is no such restrictions on MacBooks.

Answer (score 6):

if you're using Android Studio , click on res -> Layout and right click on your landscape layout -> Delete

uncheck (safe Delete) and the other option.
click ok.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can switch the way you view your projects. On top left corner of your Android Studio you should see a menu that changes the view options of your project. You probably deleted from the "Android" view, try switching to "Project" view, there you should be able to pick file directly from src/main/res/layout folder.